# How to add logic to Webform

Tags: 7, webforms

Using webform 3 module, how to add logic to my multi-step form so that I can choose what to display on second step based on the choice from step1?

I have been successful doing this using Forms API, but then I loose the ability to do webform reporting(analytics). Is it possible to combine form (design, analytics and  validation) using "webform module" with logic using Forms API? or is there a better solution?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears [Webforms](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform#webform-vs-cck) has conditional rules which works great. Also there is a module called [Webform Conditional](http://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) for in page conditional statements.